# How to upgrade node from an old homebrew installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I got the following error when I upgrade node (from a 2012 installation) in homebrew. Does anybody know how to fix the problem.

```
$ npm

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Comment: Upgrade _how_?  What were you doing when you got this error? Because if you're using `brew`, you shouldn't be. For Node.js, you want to be using https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm which is infinitely better at managing Node installs.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Does `brew reinstall node` fixes the issue?

Comment: I uninstalled it from homebrew then installed using the installer from node's website. Now it works.